# VMWare Guest Accessing Host Statistics

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I have tried researching this but unfortunately couldn't come across an answer.

Is it possible for a vmware esx virtual machine to access statistics about its host machine such as CPU and memory usage?

I have found its possible to build a client that can sign into the host as a user and get statistics this way however i was wondering could the information be gotten through some vmware API or bus accessible from the client?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SSH into your ESXi host and execute;

```
esxtop
```

https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.monitoring.doc%2FGUID-D89E8267-C74A-496F-B58E-19672CAB5A53.html